# linking git and todo lists

Tags: git, knowledge-management, ticket-system

### Desired:

I'd like to be have my git commits reference some higher order/level task or todo list.

### Background:

I use Git as my version control.  Now, DVCS is great.  A great side effect is that the log should contain, with some care, an atomic list of the actions taken to achieve a task.  This is the bottom level of a '[knowledge base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base)' really, since a third party, reading the log would know what actions were taken to solve a problem.  That's nice.

Now , I am seeking a way to link 'todo list' or more generally, higher level tasks to my commits.

ie:  "Resolving task $TASK":

- commit log entry 1
- commit log entry 2
- commit log entry 3

The end result would be a task linked with the atomic actions used to achieve it, which for many tasks would become a knowledge base , ticketing and project management solution.

Does something like this exist?  Or do I have to fall back to a wiki or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'a more the opposite direction but there are issue tracker (e.g. [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages)) who can detect ticket numbers in the commit message and link commits to the related ticket.

Answer (score 3):

> Does something like this exist?

ticketing systems can have a Git plugin achieving just that.

For instance, [Jira has a Git plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/4984):

[image]

[image]